# Как улучшить читабельность в терминале?

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

Проблема в том, что мне нравится большой шрифт в коноли, но когда я запрашиваю документацию по конкретной утилите, то все вылезает в очень не удобном виде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите какие нибудь плагины для улучшения читабельности. Добавление табличных линий, например. Я использую zsh.

Comment: Это зависит от консоли. Зайди в настройки, поменяй шриф и его размер, а также дефолтный размер самой консоли. Например в Kubuntu дефолтно стоит Konsole. Какие тебе табличные линии? Это просто текст выводимый в консоль. Учись читать такой текст, это полезно. Люди логи на бегу читают в худшем формате порой.

Comment: Ты скоро привыкнешь и начнёшь видеть Матрицу XD

Answer (score 5):

Я так понимаю, это справка по команде `--help`?

Если да, то никак, только предварительным уменьшением шрифта или увеличением ширины консоли, чтобы всё поместилось.

Каждая утилита реализует вывод хелпа (`-h`, `--help`) по-своему, грубо говоря, он вшит в саму программу, в отличии, к примеру, от того же мана (`man`).

Насколько я могу судить по картинке — у вас ширина где-то 80 символов, это раньше, да и для большинства сегодняшних *нормальных* утилит, является *стандартом* для вывода читаемой текстовой информации в консоль, чтобы не плыла разметка (в общем, как у вас), но некоторые создатели *современных* утилит идут своим путём.